# Tablets running Ubuntu (or any other Linux distro)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

For a project for elderly people using a tablet I am searching for tablet models running with Ubuntu or any other Linux distro.

Unfortunately i couldn't find a list of models running with ubuntu/linux. Any hints?

Sofar I could find the BQ Aquaris M10. But I am not sure if the ubuntu support for the newer models is still uptodate and running...

Thanks! And cheers....

Comment: Check the tablet from https://pine64.org as it's open hardware and will have Ubuntu Touch support (as well as being able to run other systems on it).

Answer (score 1):

You can find list of devices working (and partialy working) with Ubuntu Touch [here](https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/)

As an alternative for Ubuntu Touch you can try `Postmarket OS` ([list of devices](https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/Devices)) or  `Plasma Mobile`.

But remember, that there are no native (arm-based) tablets working without any issue with regular Linux distro.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunatley the situation does not look too good for linux enthusiatiscs as I am one of them ;). I only found the BQ Aquaris M10 and the PineTab (which is not released yet) to offer satisfiying functionality (working camera, wifi, touchscreen, audio). Seems that the situation is still experimental...Hopes lie on the PineTab to be honest....

Comment: I am also an enthusiast of linux and I really hope Pinephone and Librem 5 will clear the path for linux dostributions on mobile devices. But currently almost every linux distrubution for tablets/phones is in early stage of development.

Comment: Yeah truly :) – My Librem 5 shoul be on its way...although they have issues with china and shipping these days (due to corona of course).... It is a mess, that there are no devices these days. Hopefully there will be soultion until google fully switches to its own os...

Answer (score 1):

There is now a solution! The pinetab is available now!
Check out :

https://store.pine64.org/?product=pinetab-10-1-linux-tablet

Also there is a new project which is interesting:

https://en.jingos.com/