# Can I totally replace android from a tablet with an Ubuntu (or any other Linux) distro?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, tablet

First, let me give you a little background about why I'm asking this:

I'm developing a simple GUI for a stationary bicycle that shows speed & time, and has buttons to change routine, increase/decrease resistance, etc. For what I've researched so far, a Raspberry Pi Zero 2W is more than enough to handle the problem, and I've seen many GUIs developed using the Zero+touchscreen by taking advantage of the Raspberry OS included in the Zero. The cool thing about that configuration, is that it can be set so the GUI starts when the device is turned on, so the user can't access any other app that isn't the GUI.

Now, the problem: I'm in Argentina, where a Raspberry Pi Zero 2W costs 360 USD (instead of the 15 USD that's the device's original price) due to importation taxes, taxes applied when using a foreing currency, 50% annual inflation, etc. Because of that, I was thinking that maybe, a tablet could be used, at least as a prototype, due to it being easier and cheaper to buy here, by erasing it's original Android OS and replacing it with a Linux based OS, most likely Ubuntu (that's what Raspberry Pi Os is based on, if I didn't get that wrong). Now, a very important fact to consider, is that **I don't want to install Linux in android**, like it's commonly shown or answered in most questions I've seen here, because **I don't want the user to use anything but the GUI**, I want to totally replace the OS.

Is it possible? If yes, can you tell me how, more or less, can it be performed?

Well, thanks in advance for reading this!

Mariano.

Comment: As always, the short answer to all similar questions is NO. Unless you're a coder -and- have access to all the necessary drivers you can't simply install Ubuntu in an unnamed ARM hardware. And Raspberry OS is based on Debian, not Ubuntu.

Comment: “I want to totally replace the OS. Is it possible?” ⇢ generally no. You need a very specific set of devices with very specific boot-loaders that allow the device to be unlocked and given a different operating system. Hardware manufacturers want people to treat tablets like appliances, not computers 

Comment: @ChanganAuto , Why not? I'm not a programmer but a Bioengineering advanced student. For what I underestand, the tablet is essentially a CPU, like a Raspberry, because it has it's own processor, RAM, etc. Now, having all those components, why can't I just erase the OS and install a new one? If you consider that I'm too lost or something like that and/or don't want or cannot explain it to me, feel free to point me in the direction I should be looking for to answer my question. And yes, I got it wrong, Ubuntu is based on Debian, I got that wrong, sorry. Thanks for the answer btw!

Comment: @matigo , well yes I get what manufacturers want people to treat their products like, but they're essentially computers, aren't they? Can you explain a little more what you refer to with "a very specific set of devices with very specific boot-loaders that allow the device to be unlocked and given a different operating system". Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: Because (1) ARM devices doesn't boot like traditional X86, X86_64 desktop/laptop computers. (2) you need access to the manufacturers drivers as commented before (3) you need to understand what Matigo commented as well re: (unlocked) bootloaders. In a nutshell, an ARM device isn't something for which you can boot installation media and click "next" when prompted. The reason why you can use Ubuntu on a Pi is because someone already did the work for you (and the Pis are well documented, source code is available for the necessary drivers, the boot is open, unlocked, etc.). (...)

Comment: (...) Try googling your model name + Ubuntu to see if someone has already did the job for you, typically the manufacturer or someone very close to it. Regular users just can't, period.

Comment: [See this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1236739/1222991) for a compiled list of devices and their limitations. TL;DR: don't expect much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)

Comment: @ChanganAuto , thanks for the patience and the answers! now it's clearer for me

Comment: @matigo , I checked it, thanks. I see it has huge limitations, thanks!

Comment: @karel , no, I already checed Postmarket OS, and the list of devices is very limited and most are very old devices I can get my hands one here easily, but thanks anyway for the answer!

Comment: I don't think you're looking for a supported Ubuntu release solution here. I think you're looking for an unsupported Ubuntu-based distro instead.

Comment: @karel , I don't know why you thought that, why would I choose an unsupported based distro instead of a supported one? I just wanted to know if I could replace Android OS with Ubuntu or any other Linux distro that may exist and be optimized for tablets. I'm really new to the Linux distros world, hence I asked my question here

Comment: Ask Ubuntu does not support unofficial releases of Ubuntu. Questions about unofficial releases of Ubuntu are off topic here. Ubuntu doesn't have an official release for ARM devices except for Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi, and your device is not a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: we also do not provide hardware support for devices that do not run official Ubuntu :)